# "Будет не(?)меньшею ценностью". Слитное или раздельное написание "не"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, егэ, частица-не

Предложение:

> Когда-нибудь жизнь, являясь главным смыслом живущего, будет не(?)меньшею ценностью для общества в целом...

Почему в данном случае написание раздельное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в данном случае написание раздельное?

**Частица не с формами больший, меньший, лучший, худший пишется раздельно: с не меньшим успехом; с не лучшими шансами.**

http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2331

Особенностью сравнительной степени прилагательного является то, что отрицание её *всегда* опирается на внешнее сравнение, явное или подразумеваемое.

К сожалению, после административной реформы утвердилась другая норма, которая по аналогии с другими прилагательными предлагает искать "утвердительные" контексты для слитного написания *больший* и *меньший* с *не*. **В учебных работах** с этим надо считаться.

Answer (score 2):

Василий Быков в повести “Сотников” о жизни написал так: Жизнь – вот единственная реальная ценность для всего сущего и для человека тоже. Когда-нибудь в совершенном человеческом обществе она станет категорией-абсолютом, мерой и ценою всего. **Каждая такая жизнь, являясь главным смыслом живущего, будет не меньшею ценностью для общества…”**

В данном случае подразумевается отрицание и сравнение: **не меньшею ценностью для общества, чем само общество в целом.**

В текстах встречаются  обе формы написания, но частотность выше у раздельной формы по аналогии: *не меньше, чем* и *не меньший, чем.*

В словаре рекомендуется применять слитную форму **в предложных сочетаниях:**  в неменьшей мере (степени), с неменьшим интересом (успехом). **Здесь нет сравнения, но есть определенная оценка.**

**Примеры:**

**Не меньшей** красотой отличается и Вознесенский собор ― кафедральный собор Новосибирской и Бердской епархии Русской православной церкви. [Василий Белоусов. Сибирский гигант // «Зеркало мира», 2012]

Дети просто в восторге от возможности весело провести время, а взрослые вспоминают законы физики **с неменьшей** заинтересованностью.

Другие, **с неменьшей** яростью, защищают его от нападок, восторгаются им в самых неумеренных выражениях, превозносят до небес его гений…

Борьба с подобными явлениями ― это не только экономическая, но и **в неменьшей степени** нравственная проблема.

Comment: Не только экономическая = в некоторой (известной и пр.) степени экономическая. Сравнение здесь неизбежно подразумевается.

Comment: Ну да, вот и В. Аксенов правил не знает, пишет слитно: С неменьшей скоростью, наверное, летал и пророк, который так жаждал мира, но всех перессорил. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)] И еще 65 примеров о чем-то говорят. У формы "не меньшей" - 316 примеров, но там часто присутствует союз ЧЕМ. В словаре написано, что можно использовать слитную форму. Я полагаю, что утвердительный смысл тут есть: обозначена область существования признака: успех не меньший, а может быть, даже больший.

Comment: Это "пишут" корректоры издательства в 2005 году. "Чем" всегда подразумевается при сравнительных оценках, а  если его нет в явном виде, это означает лишь, что объект сопоставления упомянут ранее.

Comment: Это Ваше мнение, но меня радует, что не все так думают. Знаете, я очень ценю Ваше участие в форуме, но мне кажется, что Вам не хватает гибкости в ваших оценках. Иногда вы преувеличиваете возможности грамматических форм и считаете, что они могут выразить все оттенки смысла,  а иногда  склоняетесь к жесткой формалистике и застывшим языковым формам. Ну не век же нам жить только по Розенталю, язык меняется, у слов появляются новые оттенки значений.